# Virtual box split virtual disk to multiple files larger than 2gb?

Tags: virtualbox, backup, vhd, vdi

I am using virtual box with several large virtual disks of 3TB each. How can i split it to files of 200gb each and still use it as one virtual harddrive? The thing is that i am trying to setup backup for the host to backup the virtual disk files, but this is highly impractical with file sizes like 3TB. Therefore, i am looking to split the virtual disks into several files of 200GB each, and backup only the once that has changed since last backup... I do notice that virtualbox has an option for this but only for 2gb...

Comment: I doubt that breaking the 3TB disks up into 1536 2GB parts each would greatly impact performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the 2GB-chunk VMDK option is to make sure, the VMDK can be stored on an FAT32 or similar file system. This seems to be the only reason to break up virtual disk files commonly thought off.

Having had the same problem, I know of this solution **only if you use VirtualBox on Linux**:

- Create your file chunks with fallocate, let's call them vhd001.raw to vhd016.raw
- attach loop devices to them:
  `losetup /dev/loop10 /path/to/vhd001.raw; losetup /dev/loop11 /path/to/vhd002.raw; ... losetup /dev/loop25 /path/to/vhd016.raw;`
- Use the MD driver to assemble them into a span without persistent superblock:
  `mdadm --build --level=linear /dev/mdX /dev/loop10 /dev/loop11 ... /dev/loop25`
- Use mdX as a raw disk image10

This is quite a hack, I recommend you go with the 2GB-VMDK option and make sure, you have enough file handles available (man ulimit)

Comment: Hmm... I guess so, it was only practical reasons that i wanted 200gb each. It could be messy trying to keep track of over 1500 files... But what happens if data is written/changed in the files while the host is taking backups? would that corrupt the files?

Comment: Another option of course is to use multiple individual disk files, and span them to a single volume in the guest os, but i am thinking from a prespective of backup... the only reason i dont want to keep the 3TB files is that i want the host to do incremental backups, but that would mean that if a change was made, it would have to re-backup the entire 3TB file... that would take days... Therefore i am looking to split, so that it only has to backup the part-files that has been changed...

Comment: 1. Using 2GB chunks increases the likelyhood of a chunk being unchanged, which is a good thing. 2. Use LVM snapshots to freeze the files for backup, but be aware, that the virtual HD is live - so restoring it means restoring to a hard-crashed instance. Use VirtualBox Snapshots if you want to be sure!